# setting apache environment variable

Tags: apache-2.2, setenv

My hosting environment using Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) and I am modifying ./usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf to set environment variable and restarting the server .

SetEnv XML-RPC-IPs 193.45.32.21

I did set it as a first entry in the file and restarted the server . But even restarting if I try to print it is still getting me black , Am I missing any thing ?

echo "My IP address ".$_SERVER['XML-RPC-IPs'];

Thanks for your help Regards Kiran

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are available in `$_ENV` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a dump of the PHP environment by setting up a page with the following code and pointing your browser to it:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

In this case, you can find your XML-RPC-IPs content in $_SERVER["XML-RPC-IPs"].

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer , I did check php info . The variable is there , but surprisingly with different name 
I mean the name I gave is "XML-RPC-IPs' ( In between hyphens ) But that came as "XML_RPC_IP" ( In between underscores ) . Not sure why ...

Comment: That's interesting indeed.  I plugged your SetEnv line into my Apache config and pulled up the phpinfo page, and the content was in $_SERVER["XML-RPC-IPs"].